# Aspect function creates blank file

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, aspect

I am trying to make get aspect from an elevation file but the code keeps making a blank file

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.overwriteOutput = True

elevation = r"C:\Geoprocessing with Python\lab08\Data\dem30"
outRaster = r"C:\Geoprocessing with Python\lab08\Data\Aspect"


env.workspace = os.path.dirname(elevation)
inputElev = os.path.basename(elevation)
saveAspect = os.path.basename(outRaster)
saveNewAspect = os.path.basename(outRaster + "math")
saveReclass = os.path.basename(outRaster + "Final")

method = "PLANAR"

outAspect = Aspect(inputElev, method)
outAspect.save(saveAspect)


northRangeone = 22.5
northRangetwo = 337.5

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

northone = Raster(outAspect) < northRangeone
northtwo = Raster(outAspect) > northRangetwo
newAspect = northone | northtwo
newAspect.save(saveNewAspect)

remap = arcpy.sa.RemapValue([[0, "NODATA"], [1, 1]])
outReclassify = Reclassify(newAspect, "Value", remap, "NODATA")
outReclassify.save(saveReclass)

arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
```